# Как обернуть текст в квадратную рамку и пропорционально подогнать под его содержимое?

Tags: html, css

Как обернуть текст в квадратную рамку (ширина и высота одинаковые)?

Можно сделать в `px`, но текст динамический.

Answer (score 2):

можно вот так

```js
setInterval (function (){
  var w = document.getElementById('blk').offsetWidth;
 document.getElementById("blk").style.height = document.getElementById('blk').offsetWidth + 'px'; 
},200);
```

```css
div {
  border:1px solid black;
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  *display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="blk">
text text text
</div>
```

Comment: Еще б прервать это надо.....

Comment: Интересно как это будет выглядеть с большим текстом......

Answer (score 1):

Можно этому блоку, где расположен текст, задать определенный стиль, в случае с рамкой используется `border`.

Пример текста в рамке:

```css
#block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div id='block'> Задача организации, в особенности же новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки существенных финансовых и административных условий. Разнообразный и богатый опыт постоянный количественный рост</div>
```

Comment: автор указывает *(ширина и высота одинаковые)*  - **квадратная** рамка

Answer (score 0):

Приводит к минимально (по размерам) возможному квадрату. Можно переделать на цикл - тогда будет более плавно

```
var i = 0, n=0, pre = 0;
var timerId = setInterval (function (){
  var w = document.getElementById('block').offsetWidth;
  var h = document.getElementById('block').offsetHeight;
  if (w == h)
  {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
  }
  else
  {
     n = ((w + h) / 2);
     if (n == pre) {
        document.getElementById("block").style.width = n + 'px'; 
        document.getElementById("block").style.height = n + 'px';
        clearTimeout(timerId);
     }
     else
     {
        if (n > w) n = w;
        document.getElementById("block").style.width = n + 'px'; 
        pre = n;
     }
  }
},200);
```